# Not getting connection string from app.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I already checked couple of sites but the issue persists. I am building a Blazor Server App. I added a DB class and trying to fetch connection string from app.config but it is coming out null. In the Program.CS itself it is not fetching from `app.config`.

`program.cs` file:

```
using DataAnalyzer.Data;
using DataAnalyzer.Data.Connection;
using DataAnalyzer.Data.Books;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<BooksService>();

var app = builder.Build();

builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").AddEnvironmentVariables().Build();
ConnectionHelper.conStr = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionStrings:Books");

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

Database class code:

```
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

namespace DataAnalyzer.Data.Connection
{
    public class ConnectionHelper
    {
        // this field gets initialized at Startup.cs
        public static string conStr;

        public static SqlConnection GetConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conStr);
                return connection;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    },
    "ConnectionStrings": {
      "Books": "data source=MyServer;User ID=TestUser;Password=TestPassword;Persist Security Info=True;initial catalog=Books;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `appsettings.json` file your `ConnectionStrings` JSON object is under `Logging` instead of being under the root object.

Reparent the `ConnectionStrings` object, like so:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Books": "data source=MyServer;User ID=TestUser;Password=TestPassword;Persist Security Info=True;initial catalog=Books;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh my .... Corrected this but in Program.cs conStr is still coming out null.

Comment: In the class, it is taking now if I simply use: IConfiguration stuff. Program.CS that line seems to be wrong.